# create instance variable dynamically in ruby unknown number variables needed

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, instance, dynamically-generated

This is the problem "I am trying to create a generic object, could be thought of as a "dynamic schema
object" each schema object will have a different number of instances variables." and this approach  doesn't work.

```
class GenericObjectArray
    def initialize
      @data_fields = []
    end
    def data_fields(t)
      @data_fields << t
    end
   def initialize(attrs = {})
      attrs.each { |attr,val| instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", val } 
   end
   end

p GenericObjectArray.new(:data_fields=>  "may_sales", :data_fields=>"june_sales", :data_fields=>"july_sales")
```

> This is my approach, bu it doesnt work.  I would like to set may_sales, june_sales, july_sales as an instance variables. Set all three as  instance variables. It only returns that last one.
>   GenericObjectArray:0x007f8c5b883cd8 @data_fields="july_sales"

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html?

Comment: You'd be better off starting with "this is the problem I'm trying to solve and this approach doesn't work" rather than "how do I force my approach to work?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it from this approach:

- You have objects (lets say GenericObject)

  - Objects have many attributes (GenericObject#attributes => [GenericObject::Attribute])

    - Attributes have a name, a value, and a type (GenericObject::Attribute#value, #name and #type)

Which translates into code like this:

```
class GenericObject
  attr_accessor :attributes

  def add_attribute(name, value, type)
    (@attributes ||= []) << Attribute.new(name, value, type) 
  end

  class Attribute
    attr_accessor :name, :value, :type
    def initialize(name, value, type)
      @name, @value, @type = name, value, type
    end
  end
end

# so...
cat = GenericObject.new
cat.add_attribute :leg_number, 4, :integer
cat.add_attribute :fur_color, 'Orange', :color
cat.add_attribute :name, 'Garfield', :string

cat.attributes.each { |attr| puts "My cat's #{attr.name} is #{attr.value} (#{attr.type})" }
# My cat's leg_number is 4 (integer)
# My cat's fur_color is Orange (color)
# My cat's name is Garfield (string)
```

You can make a fancy initializer for GenericObject or whatever you see fit.
**Or you can just to a little fix**

```
class GenericObjectArray
  def initialize(attrs = {})
    attrs.each { |attr,val| instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", val } 
  end
end

GenericObjectArray.new(:data_fields=> ["may_sales", "june_sales", "july_sales"])
```

Comment: I could have (name, value, typeA) OR (name, value, typeA, typeB)

Comment: Thanks Nicooga, but since I do not know the number of attributes this will not work for me.

Comment: I don't follow you, this implementation permits for an object to have n number of attributes (?.

Comment: Sorry, I am not explaining this correctly  I could have attr.name, attr.value, attr.type, attr.element1, attr.element2, attr.element3.  The number of attributes vary and is unknown. So cannot code this "(name, value, type)"

Comment: Are you trying to make some sort of tree structure (like if it was xml)? Otherwise, an array of attributes means 'unlimited' attributes, each having name, type and value; I don't get where are you going with "The number of attributes vary and is unknown"..

Comment: I want to create an instance variable for each data_field.  For example, if I have the following data_fields:may_sales, june_sales, july_sales.  I want an instance variables for each: may_sales, june_sales and july_sales. Code above only returns that last one. GenericObjectArray:0x007f8c5b883cd8 @data_fields="july_sales"

Comment: It returns the last one because you are just overriding the instance variable over and over, or more probably because the hash ignores duplicate keys. A hash can't have duplicate keys. Also, ruby does not support method overloading,

Comment: Hi Nicooga, thank you!!! Your code provides the correct solution.  Much appreciated!